# Synchronizing between a local and remote GUI

Tags: c++, qt

Consider the following GUI:

[image]

when the user press the + button the value is incremented to 6.

However on another computer another user is running the same GUI.

The two GUIs have to stay in sync.
If one of the users press the + button the value should be updated for both GUIs.

The remote GUI, the client, communicate with the local server via a simple protocol.
The communication takes the form of a cmd sent from the client and a response sent from the server. There are two commands:

```
1. cmd:"GET_VALUE", response: "5"
2. cmd: "INCREMENT", response: "OK"
```

Unfortunately the client has to poll GET_VALUE to be notified,
but the protocol albeit flawed can not be changed.

How can I implement this in Qt, C++?

So far I have come up with the following classes (rough outline):

```
class Model {
public:
    std::atomic<int> m_value;
};

class Widget : public QWidget {
public slots:
    void incrementClickedLocally(); // must update Model::m_value somehow
    void valueChangedFromModel(int value); // will update the QLineEdit
};

// Reads synchronously from TCP/IP using WinSocket and works on the Model 
class RemoteHandler : public QThread {
private:
    void run override();
};
```

I would like to use signals/slots to communicate across the threads.
However it seems that the `RemoteHandler` can not use signal/slots to get the `Model::m_value` since slots can not have return types?

Further it would be convenient to emit a `valueChanged` signal from Model to notify Widget. However in order to do that Model must be a QObject.
It seems that when Model becomes a QObject there are many potential thread problems I have to look out for?
As it is `Model` is threadsafe. I can therefore request `Model::m_value` directly from the non main thread in `RemoteHandler` while the Widget may be accessing the same variable simultaneously from the main thread.

Comment: Have you considered the obvious problem of what happens if both users press + at the same time?

Comment: @TanveerBadar: I would like the value to jump from 5 to 7 in both GUIs. Ensuring that this happens is part of the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the need for threads here.  Presumably you're using TCP?  That being the case a local user instigated increment should provoke an `INCREMENT` message to the remote host and an `INCREMENT` message from the remote host should cause a local programmatic increment.

Comment: Guess the main problem of your setup is how a remote client is notified about an updated value it did not trigger itself. Every client would need to continuously request `GET_VALUE` in order to keep its value synchronized.

Comment: @G.M.: unfortunately the local server can not message the client that the value has been updated. The client has to poll. Therefore the client generates a lot of messages and that is why I want to communicate with it in a separate thread.

Comment: To ensure both UIs are showing the latest values, use a high polling rate. To ensure that race condition doesn't occur, serialize and protect access to the value in the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It **cannot** work with those commands.

The logic is well-known from the design of multi-core CPU's. You need Compare-and-Swap (CAS), Load-Link/Store Conditional (LL/SC) or something equally powerful. With the weak protocol you have, it can be proven that the race conditions are unsolvable.